# Single user is being logged in across all devices

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase-authentication

I was building a project on node.js recently, I came across this bug of user authentication. The problem is that after I log in from one account, if at the same time I refresh the home page of the website from another device, it redirects to the dashboard of the first user account. In other words, a single user is getting logged in on all the devices over the network. If suppose I don't refresh the page, and I log in normally on the application, it works fine. This problem is happening, both on the localhost as well as after hosting it on Heroku. Technologies used- node.js for handling back-end views and URLs. HTML, CSS, JavaScript for the front-end. Firebase for the database and authentication. Here is the code for the login part-

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

//Create Router Object.
const router = express.Router();

//Main Login Page (GET)
router.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve("./views/html/login.html"));
});

//Main Login Page (POST)
router.post("/", (request, response) => {
    let email = request.body.email;
    let password = request.body.password;
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(r => {
            let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if (user.emailVerified)
                response.redirect('/dashboard');
            else
                response.send("<h1>Please Verify your email address.</h1>");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            response.send("<h1>Invalid Credentials</h1>");
        });
});
```

Please can someone help me by resolve this bug in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` signs the user in on the location wherever you call this code. Since you run this in an express.js app in Node.js, the user is signed in to that Node.js process, until you sign them out again. This is why the Firebase Authentication SDK you are using is only meant to be used in client-side applications, where this behavior is working as intended.

When integrating Firebase Authentication in a server-side process, you should use the Firebase Admin SDK. This Admin SDK has no concept of a currently logged in user, and no `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. Instead, if you need to know the identity of the user accessing the server-side code, you'll:

1. Sign the user in in their client-side app with the Firebase Authentication SDK.
2. Get the ID token for that user on the client, and pass that with your call to the server.
3. On the server, verify that ID token, to ensure the user is who they claim they are.
4. Then use the information on the user's identity to determine if they're authorized to access the information.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).